# C# Method: How to make two sets of overloads? Edit: Parameters, not overloads

Tags: c#, class, methods, overloading

I have some where code I reuse a part of it 3 times with different overloads.

Therefore the overload looks like this:

```
    int[] DateCounterReturns = CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(answerDay, answerMonth, answerYear, false, false, 0);
```

Two other places, I have to use the same method differently, and I therefore need different overloads. The false, false, 0 looks a bit overdone to me here as it is not needed.

Is it possible to say to the method "you either take the three first overloads (here called answerDay, answerMonth, answerYear), or all 6!"?

Let's say I have to use the same method 30 times in different ways - Would I then have to make an endless stream of overloads in the same line? Or can it be grouped or filtered in a way?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what your *real* problem is, not how you think it can be solved? Or why you don't just use a `DateTime` or even a custom class for the (single) parameter?

Comment: You're confusing overload with parameter throughout your explanation

Comment: *an endless stream of overloads in the same line*. Are you sure you are talking about overloading here. Looks like *optional parameters*.

Comment: Form your question, it's not clear if you know what overload means...  Method overloading is the case where you have two or more methods with the same name but different arguments. Now that we got that part clear, please rephrase your question.

Comment: i think you are looking for optional parameter/default parameter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Comment: Oh I see. I must be confused then.

When I hover over a class with a method attached it says "takes x overloads" like 21 or something. I always figured those overloads were x sets of parameters or ways to use this method by entering different types of things.

What I want then is to be able to only input the parameters I want to put in. Like if I'm only using 3 somewhere, I want to put in 3 only, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

An overload in this case is where we are calling the same method, but with different parameters.

You have one underlying DateCounter, which accepts 6 parameters that has all of your logic in it, but in some cases you're only interested in the day, month & year whilst the other 3 options can just be a default value. So this overload lets you only enter those 3 variables and then inside of it you call your main, underlying DateCounter method and pass in your default parameters as essentially hard coded values.

All it's doing is saving you from having to enter the 3 optional parameters.

```
public int[] CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(int answerDay, int answerMonth, int answerYear)
{
   return CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(answerDay, answerMonth, answerYear, false, false, 0);
}
```

In this case, the last 3 parameters are optional. This is indicated by the = {value}. e.g. for optionalBoolA, if you don't specifically put in a value for it, it will set it to false.

You can then just call it with the 3 parameters

```
CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(10, 10, 2018);
```

Or, you can fill in those values too:

```
CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(10, 10, 2018, true, true, 1);

public int[] CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(int answerDay, int answerMonth, int answerYear, bool optionalBoolA = false, bool optionaloolB = false, int optionalIntA = 0);
```

In newer versions of c# you can use this shorthand. It's just the same as the first one but c# wires it up for you.

```
public int[] CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(int answerDay, int answerMonth, int answerYear) => CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(answerDay, answerMonth, answerYear, false, false, 0);
```

When you are using Visual Studio and you enter CalendarDateTime.DateCounter(

It will show you what your overloads are and using the up and down arrows will tell you what the parameters are.

Comment: Thank you :) I bet all these will work, but I'm not good enough at coding to understand why they will work, or how they will work, from this code alone. Is it possible to explain how each way works?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! I'll give these a go and see what works best.